# A funky thing with Autocomplete (Strings and Int)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, autocomplete

I am hoping that someone here can help me understand why this is happening. . .

I have an MVC5/C# Application.  I am using Autocomplete to allow the user to begin typing characters to filter.  Overall, it works great.  But there is one little funky thing that is driving me bonkers.

The Autocomplete box is populated from a SQL Table (ICS_Supplies).  The search field in the table is Old_ItemID, which a varchar(25), as some Item ID's are letters, and some are numeric and some are combination.  This is not an int field - which is why I am banging my head here.

There is another field called Inv_Type.   This field designates whether the supply item is a Form, or a Supply.  F is forms, and G is supplies.   This is part of the puzzle!

Here is my View Autocomplete Element

```
<div>
<label>Form Item Number Search</label>
<input class="form-control" id="searchInput" />
</div>
```

Here is my script

```
<script>
$("#searchInput").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSearchValue", "AutoComplete")',
            datatype: "json",
            data: { search: $("#searchInput").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.Old_ItemID, value: item.Old_ItemID };

                }))
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
});

</script>
```

And Here is my Controller

```
public JsonResult GetSearchValue(string search)
    {
       ICSContext db = new ICSContext();
        
       var allsearch = db.ICS_Supplies.Where(s => s.InvType == "G" && s.Discontinued == "N" && s.Old_ItemID.Contains(search)).ToList();

       return new JsonResult { Data = allsearch, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

So, here is the quirky thing I can't figure out:

s.InvType == "G" (Supplies only, which usually start with alpha characters) works fine.
s.InvType == "F" (Forms, only - which are normally numeric, like 0057 or 7813) works fine.

But, if I run it without filtering on F or G, but allowing both to be searched simultaneously, it gives me an Error on the Forms every time:  alert("Error");

If my field InvType is Varchar(25) - why does it even matter if the search is a numeric?  And why does it work perfectly fine when filtered on F or G - but not both?  It's a varchar field . . I don't get it?

Certainly, I can make an autocomplete for Forms and separate one for Supplies.  But that's not the direction I want to go.  It's unnecessary and clunky

Comment: You need to get closer to the source of the error. You likely have an unhandled exception resulting in a 500 error. If you put a try/catch around the method body, do you get an exception? What is it?

Comment: @madreflection - Thanks for your response.  All I got was an Internal Server Error.  But I noticed something peculiar.  If I type '1' in the search box, I get the error.  If I type '17' in the box, I get an error.  If I type the first three numerics '178' it works properly.   Could it be that the one and two numeric searches bring back too many results causing it to fail?

Comment: If all you're seeing is "Internal Server Error", you're still too far away from the source of the error. If you haven't added the try/catch around the code in the *action method* (`GetSearchValue`), do that now. Put a breakpoint inside the catch block and add the exception message and stack trace to the post. Without that, it's all guesswork.

Comment: @madreflection - Understood.  The issue is that, the GetSearchValue method does not fail, and therefore it did not kick an error.  The only error I get is from the script side.  That being said, I just put a few stops in the method to ensure it's yielding results.  And I think I was on the right path with the recordset being too large.  When I search on just '1', it brings back almost 10,000 possibilities.  When it comes to numerics, it might be that I need 3 characters to filter enough to have a small enough set of results to work?

Comment: @madreflection - seeing that the issue is, most likely, driven by the huge amount of results with just one numeric character search  . what if I simply remove the error alert in the script?  When I do that, it works perfect!  It does not fail with one number. . . it just waits for the second or third before it filters.  And that is okay.   We can work with that.   Question is - will that cause hidden problems ?  I don't see any performance issue by doing that - on the client side.

Comment: I would recommend limiting your results instead (e.g. `.Take(100)` or something manageable like that) so that you don't have to lose real error handling, plus it might improve query performance (although with a *contains* test on a string, that's questionable). `alert` may not be the best thing for error handling, either, but you might still need to know if there's an error and possibly give a more passive indicator.

Comment: As for "hidden problems", until you know the nature of the issue, you're always going to have the risk of hidden problems. Find the root cause. If your action method succeeds but you still get a 500 error, figure that out. Getting it to work for now is nice, and it could help you with the root cause analysis, but so far you're just *masking* the problem and it could easily come back to bite you in unforeseen ways.

Comment: @madreflection Thanks for all the great information.  I do get your point.  My problem is that Jscript is not a comfort zone for me. I am very new to it.  The method is working fine. The Try Catch in the method never gets to 'catch'. .   It appears to be the 10,000 records it brings back on a 1 digit search that is driving the issue.  I can see the list when I put stops in the controller.  So, it has to be the jscript side and my I don't know much to troubleshoot that.  I will add a limit of records, as you suggested.

Comment: Side note: "JScript" is Microsoft's ActiveScript-based implementation of ECMAScript (read the tag). IE 11 still uses it and old Edge might have (I don't know for sure, though), but new (Chromium-based) Edge and all other modern browsers don't. Best to speak of "JavaScript" since you're probably not specifically targeting JScript at this point (and replace the [tag:jscript] tag with [tag:javascript]).